# Bi-Directionnal Replication With SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication

Is there a way to make a bi-directionnal Replication with SQL Server ?

(BDD 1) Table 1 <=> (BDD 2) Table 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions that might suit your need.

1. [Merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx)
2. [Peer to peer transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx)
3. [Database mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934127.aspx)

Each of them has its own advantages and disadvantages. Choosing one depends on the nature of your scenario.

Comment: Does Merge Replication is an Instant Replication ? or it's differed ?

Comment: It's usually used for deferred situations. If DB servers are always available, you could use database mirroring instead.

Comment: my problem is to prevent from one of the db servers get down. So i needed a 2 way instant replication between the 2 servers whenever they are onlines. And if one of the server is down, update the database when goes up.

Comment: Yaonn. B: I think database mirroring is specifically designed for such a situation.